# Increase width of divs, displayed side by side, using draggable events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have two divs of fixed length as of now, which loads external URL by dynamically embedding iframes inside them. Divs are appearing next to each other - one on left and other right.

As of now, I have fixed their width to `50%` each. But, I want to give user a flexibility to increase the width of any div to view the URL inside easily `without scrolling horizontally`. Something like dragging the border separating the two divs to either left or right according to his need.

Is there a way I could achieve this? Please suggest any library or something.

I have gone through a library [twentytwenty](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Stylish-jQuery-Images-Comparison-Plugin-twentytwenty/) which is used for images. I don't know how will that work for dynamic iframes.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vw9qt/) which displays the divs.

```html
<div>
    <div id="originalPage" style="width:54%;height: 730px;float:left">  
        <p>one div </p>
    </div>
    <div id="diffReport" style="width:45%; height: 730px;float:right">
        <p>another div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to admit that it's too much work for me now, but I would suggest that you create CSS that changes cursor when you hover the center area. Then, attach handler for mousedown/mouseclick. Then, when the user moves mouse, you compare the mouseposition and set the new widths of the divs. Sounds like a plan..?

Comment: Yes. I am also thinking in the same direction. The answer @Linus gave would do the trick i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

There is a awesome jQuery plugin, go with jQuery Splitter here:

http://jquery.jcubic.pl/splitter.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div class="resizable" id="originalPage" style="width:54%;height: 730px;float:left">  
        <p>one div </p>
    </div>
    <div class="resizable" id="diffReport" style="width:45%; height: 730px;float:right">
                <p>another div</p>
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {$( ".resizable" ).resizable({animate: true,animateEasing:'swing',imateDuration: 500
});});

#diffReport, #originalPage{
        border: 1px solid;
}
.ui-resizable-helper { border: 1px dotted gray; }
.resizable { display: block; width: 400px; height: 400px; padding: 30px; border: 2px solid     gray; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
#diffReport { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#originalPage { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Play a little with the CSS width and height of #diffReport and #original to achieve what you want. Let me know if it's ok.

Comment: This works somewhat but while increasing the width of left div, right one goes down. And there is no option of increasing width of right by dragging its left border which user will need ideally. Draggable events are ok, but we need that if we are dragging one div, other's size should automatically decrease so that it doesn't goes below.

Comment: Mmm ye because both have same class (my bad) so they both get resized. Change that. Can't help you more at the moment :/

Answer (score 0):

1. `var isDragging = false`
2. `var lastPageX = null`
3. Make a new div in the middle of the existing ones.
4. Attach an event listener to `mousedown` on that div.

   - set `isDragging` to `true` and `lastPageX` to `event.pageX`
5. Attach an event listener to `mousemove` on the enclosing div.

   - only run if `isDragging`
   - `var diff event.pageX - lastPageX`
   - add `diff` to the left resizable div
   - remove `diff` from the right resizable div
   - set `lastPageX` to `event.pageX`
6. Attach an event listener to `mouseup` on the `document`

   - set `isDragging` to `false`

Comment: `add/remove that value to the two resizable divs` , unable to understand this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery UI library in order to do resizing/dragging.

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**Script**

```
    <script>
    $(function(){$('#demo').draggable().resizable();});

    $('#demo')
        .resizable({
            start: function(e, ui) {
                alert('resizing started');
            },
            resize: function(e, ui) {

            },
            stop: function(e, ui) {
                alert('resizing stopped');
            }
        });
</script>
```

Fiddle is

http://jsfiddle.net/VuqbN/

Updated your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vw9qt/1/